# Joomla Ajax Menu- refreshless content

Tags: ajax, menu, joomla, deep-linking

I am trying to convert a flash site into a non-flash site. The site is already powered by Joomla CMS but it outputs XML into flash. You can see the site here www.alexandraandthesunflowers.com.

As you can see (and hear) there is a music player that persists across all pages in the site (i.e. the page does not refresh when you go to different sections)

To achieve this without flash I think what I need to do is frame the home page with the main Joomla menu and a media playing component. Then what I need is for the main menu to load Joomla content into the content area using ajax and use some equivalent of SwfAddress to enable the back and forwards buttons to work and for the pages to be directly linkable.

Things like edcwid seem to work like this (ie www.carpaholixx.com/estore) but I cannot find any information anywhere on how to go about getting Joomla to work this way...

Has anyone got any ideas?

D

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the frame solution could be interesting.
I suggest making a frameset like this:

```
<frameset>
    <frame id="mediaplayer" src="mediaplayer.htm" />
    <frame id="main" src="{Joomla main page}" />
</frameset>
```

And then use css to hide the #mediaplayer, and custom javascript inserted on the joomlapage to send commands to the #mediaplayer frame where you run any kind of mediaplayer with a JS interface.

So keep the transport controls on your Joomla page and keep the mediaplayer over several changes of the #main frame.

Hope this makes sense :)

You could also consider using a javascript API to take care of the AJAX fetching of a page, to insert it in a content container on the page. This however require that you disable the header/footer of any Joomla page you request via this method. I however don't know if this is possible using Joomla.